# nodejs pass value from one module to another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

in my self-defined module I have this method which will query the db and find if the username exists in my db. I want some values to be returned so in the upper level I will know the query result.

```
var findUserbyUsername=function(username)
{
    db.users.find({email:username},function(err,result)
    { 

        if(err|!username) {console.log('username not found'); return 0;} 
        else return 1;
    }
    );
}
module.exports.findUser=findUserbyUsername;
```

in app.js I will call the above method like this

```
var lt=dbutil.findUser('xxxx@gmail.com');
```

but unfortunately I got undefined....
Can anyone help me workaround this ? Or any other suggestions ?

Comment: I understood the reason. thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an asynchronous code, of course it's not going to return anything. You might want the following:

app.js:

```
dbutil.findUser( 'xx@gmail.com', function( err, data ) {
    if ( err ) throw err;
    // Handle the datas returned "data"
} );
```

module:

```
var findUserByUserName = function( username, callback ) {
    db.users.find( { email: username }, function( err, result ) {
       if ( err || !username ) {
           console.log( 'username not found' );

           // Call the function passed as parameter
           callback( err ); // You give "undefined" as second parameter
       }
       else {
           callback( err, result ); // You give the datas back
       }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `findUserbyUsername` function does not return anything, that is why you get `undefined`. Since database operations are asynchronous in Node, then cannot return anything meaningful and work via callbacks. Change your code like this:

```
var findUserbyUsername = function(username, callback) {
    db.users.find({ email: username }, function(err, result) { 
        if (err || !username) {
            console.log('username not found');
            callback(err? err: 'Username not found');
        } else {
            callback(null, whateverYouWantToReturn);
        }
    });
}
module.exports.findUser = findUserbyUsername;
```

and use it like this:

```
dbutil.findUser('xxxx@gmail.com', function(err, result) {
    // you have the result from findUserbyUsername() in "result", and "err" is set if there was an error
});
```

(*Note:* I have also fixed your condition `if(err|!username)`, since `|` is a bitwise operator and you actually want the `||` logical operator)

(Edit: added de-facto standard `err` parameter to the callback)

Comment: Hey! don't forget the `err` parameter, a standard in node :-) I'll delete my answer after that.

Comment: nice :) just to nitpick, why not keep it consistent and use `err` instead of `null`? Btw, looks like I can't delete an "accepted answer", sorry :(

Comment: It seems more explicit and readable. Makes it clear that you already have determined that there is no error at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have an asynchronous request inside your function, so the return inside the db.users.find is in the wrong scope, and will never get back to your request.

You need to pass a callback function as a second parameter so the code looks like this:

```
var findUserbyUsername=function(username, cb)
{
    db.users.find({email:username}, cb);
}
module.exports.findUser=findUserbyUsername;
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
dbutil.findUser('xxxx@gmail.com', function(err, username) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle err
    } else {
      // Handle username
    }
})
```