# Returning/getting object from a module in nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mongodb, module, express

I am working on a nodejs app.

Folder structure is

```
app
app.js
package.json
../model/schema.js
../controller/controller.js
../views
```

All the logic is in controller.js while app.js performing routing itself....

I want to know how to get/return data(object) from controller.js to app.js.

I am using 'return' to send mongodb document from controller to app but its undefined.

Heres code of app.js..i have removed unneccessary code

```
  var express = require('express'),
   app = express.createServer(express.logger()),
   io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
   routes = require('./routes');
   var controller=require('./controller/controller');
   var model=require('./model/schema');

   app.get("/", function(req, res) {
     res.render("chatroom.html");
    });

   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('login',function(user)
      {
          var onliner=controller.loginUser(user);
          console.log("Onlinersss: ",onliner);
      });

      socket.on('registerUser',function(user){
          controller.registerUser(user);
      });
   });
```

Heres controller.js code:

```
  var model=require('../model/schema');
  exports.loginUser=function(user)
  {

      model.registerUser.findOne({uname:user.uname,pass:user.pass},function(err,doc){
        if(!err){ 
             console.log("Here loggedin: ",doc); 
             return doc;             
        }
        else
             console.log("Invalid username or password");
        });
  };
```

Comment: Heres the detailed explanation and code for the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928471/nodejs-pass-value-from-one-module-to-another-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just pushed a project to [GitHub](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-example-nodejs-chat) that uses pretty much the same libraries and [RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com) as the database (very similar to MongoDB). Basically you need to pass `callbacks` to your controller and have them invoked with the data retrieved from the DB. Take a look at app.js and lib/db.js in the linked project.

Comment: Yes callbacks are used for the scenario...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (and therefore node.js) is asynchronous. When you 'return doc' the anonymous function defined at `function(err, doc)` is returned... not the function loginUser that you are trying to get data from.

loginUser returns immediately, and it returns undefined (since you don't specify anything else). To see what I mean, put 'return true;' as the last line in loginUser and you'll notice that you get the value back of 'true.'

However, you don't want to return a value. You want to callback with a value. That's beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer, so here is a good resource:

http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/asynchronous-javascript-the-tale-of-harry/

Comment: Yeah .. I got you its the function(err,doc) which is returned but I am not getting this harry's tutorial.

Comment: Please suggest any other way ..?

Comment: I just got my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928471/nodejs-pass-value-from-one-module-to-another-module